# How to install AWS CLI Version 2 on Cygwin

Tags: command-line, cygwin, amazon-web-services

Most questions that I've come across on this issue solve it by using Python package managers, but these are all outdated methods that install the Version 1 of the `AWS CLI` command-line tool.

I tried following [Amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html#cliv2-linux-install) to install Version 2 of `AWS CLI` on Cygwin, but when running the install script:

```
./aws/install
```

I get the error:

```
./aws/install: line 78: /cygdrive/d/Users/User/Desktop/aws/dist/aws: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I believe this means that the the binary in question was designed to be run on Linux, even though I recall using this method to install the tool on Windows 7 just a few months ago.

The only other method that I can see is to use the MSI installer, but this is messy for two reasons:

1. It won't be a case of a few binaries that I can move into `/bin`, but a directory full of dependencies that probably shouldn't be moved or messed with
2. I can't use the MSI to install it directly to my Cygwin because of permissions errors ("The installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory") and I'm wary of changing the permissions of the Cygwin directory recursively because I've been burnt by that before

So as of 2020, what is the best and cleanest way to install Version 2 of the `AWS CLI` for Cygwin?

Comment: you can not run/install a Linux binary on Cygwin. Eventually you can run it under WSL

Comment: I managed this way: `git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-cli; git checkout v2; pip install -r requirements.txt; pip install -r .` however I am getting an error in the end of the process :(

Comment: I saw one about the version of botocore not available trying with Cygwin Python-3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I opted for in the end was to install the [MSI installer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-windows.html#cliv2-windows-install) for Windows. Although this results in the binary being installed to `C:\Program Files` rather than directly to Cygwin's `/bin` directory like I would have liked, the installer automatically adds the binary to the PATH so it can be immediately run from within a Cygwin shell (you may need to reboot to get Windows to recognise the changed PATH).

Comment: I want to add that, under Windows 7 (yeah, I'm still happily using it), you have to limit yourself to using AWS CLI v2.4.29, since later versions use embedded versions of Python that are not compatible with Win7 anymore.

Comment: @CharlesRobertoCanato There's a good reason for that. Windows 7 has been EOLed since the beginning of 2020. That's more than 3 years' worth of unfixed bugs and exploits. If you're connecting to the internet, you should definitely not be using Windows 7 anymore unless you're happy with being hacked.

Comment: I definitely respect your opinion - I would never argue against a good security recommendation. However, I'm still happy with my environment stability and completeness (it just works). Yeah it's just laziness of going to the great Win10. :-)

Comment: This is still the easiest way in 2023.  Install the Windows version, put the corresponding directory into `PATH` (either Windows' version of PATH, or inside Cygwin in an appropriate dotfile).  The only hitch is trying to use it from inside a shell script, since the Windows version uses <CRLF> line terminators when running with `aws --output text`.  It's relatively painless to do something like `aws() { command aws "$@" | tr -d '\r' }` (but with correct shell syntax) for a drop-in function solution.